# Член ряда через рекурсию

Tags: рекурсия

С помощью рекурсии найти любой член этого ряда

[image]

Comment: Что конкретно Вас интересует или непонятно?

Comment: Дан ряд : 1/ (1*2) ; 1/(2*3); 1/(3*4) .. 1/(n*(n-1)). Через рекурсию найти любой член данного ряда. Как это сделать?

Comment: Тогда получается, что в конце не `n-1`, а `n+1`, верно?

Comment: Вы правильно поняли, извините

Comment: Я имел в виду, что именно Вам нужно обьяснить, какой конкретный вопрос? Вам непонятна сама рекурсия или как реализовать ее на каком-то конкретном языке программирования? Если и то, и другое, то желательно расширить Ваш вопрос и уточнить, что именно Вам непонятно, чтобы легче было помочь или подсказать ответ.

Comment: Что такое рекурсия я , вроде бы, понял, но пока что не хватает практики, чтобы хорошо ею пользоваться. Я решаю задачи на рекурсию и встал в тупик. Не знаю как решить конкретно эту задачу.

Comment: Вам на каком языке программирования это нужно?

Comment: Лучше на c#, но вообще лучше суть алгоритма показать, так что на любом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что такое рекурсия я , вроде бы, понял, но пока что не хватает практики, чтобы хорошо ею пользоваться. Я решаю задачи на рекурсию и встал в тупик. Не знаю как решить конкретно эту задачу.

Смотрите. На самом деле все очень просто. В задачах с рекурсией нужно найти что-то вроде повторяющегося паттерна. В этой задаче мы видим, что сумма `n` элементов сводится к сумме `n - 1` элементов + элемент №`n`. Но мы ведь не можем до бесконечности проходить через эту подстановку, она должна когда-нибудь закончится? Да, закончится она, когда мы дойдем до `n = 1` и сумма при таком значении `n` будет просто 1/2. Это называется *терминальная ветвь* рекурсии.

Таким образом мы получаем формулу:

```
Сумма(n) = 1 / (n * (n + 1)) + Сумма(n - 1),
Сумма(1) = 1 / 2.
```

Которая легко реализуется в коде:

```
double sum(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1.0 / 2.0;

    return 1.0 /  (n * (n + 1.0)) + sum(n - 1);
}
```